# How can I reuse some parts of my tests?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I need to implement following logic:

1. Do something
2. Check logic
3. Do something other
4. Similar check logic

I used `when`/`then` blocks for simple tests. But I really don't know how to implement more complicated one (like described above) + I would like to reuse code as much as possible. But with blocks it becomes more complicated to implement

Comment: Do you face any problem if you move your logic to private methods and simply use like `when: doThis() then: checkThis() when: doThat() then: checkThat()` (obviously indented as per spock standard)?

Comment: Either that, or use `@spock.lang.StepWise`. The latter is useful for integration and acceptance tests.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches I take to reusing code in Spock.

**Feature Level**
Create a closure within your setup: block. You can treat it like a method that's available to only this feature.

```
def "test"() {
    setup:
        def containsCat = {String it -> it.contains('cat')}
    expect:
        !containsCat('I love my dog')
        containsCat('I love my cat')
}

def "test that cannot reference containsCat(String)"() {
    // Test stuff
}
```

**Spec Class Level**
While it is possible to use a @Shared closure, my preference is to use private helper methods unless the helper logic is just one or two lines.

```
class tester extends Specification {
@Shared
def containsDog = {String it -> it.contains('dog')}
private containsCat(String inputString) {
    inputString.contains('cat')
}

def "test"(String myPet) {
    expect: containsCat(myPet)
    where: myPet = 'I love my cat'
}

def "test2"() {
    expect: containsDog(mySistersPet)
    where: mySistersPet = 'I love my dog'
}
```

**Package Level**
I have a group of classes that could all benefit from sharing a miniature testing framework.  My preference is to use traits. They can hold any code except for a Feature test itself.  If the trait will reference data from within the test itself, make sure to create an abstract method so the trait is ensured a reference to the data.

```
trait petTester {
    private containsDog(String inputString) {
        inputString.contains('dog')
    }    
    private containsCat(String inputString) {
        inputString.contains('cat')
    }    
}

class myPetTester extends Specification implements petTester {
    def "test"(String myPet) {
        expect: containsCat(myPet)
        where: myPet = 'I love my cat'
    }
}

class mySistersPetTester extends Specification implements petTester {
    def "test2"() {
        expect: containsDog(mySistersPet)
        where: mySistersPet = 'I love my dog'
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the same test twice, just changing some parameters, you can use `where`:

```
  def "foo"(Boolean barIsEnabled) {
      when:
      myService.testBar(barIsEnabled)

      then:
      myService.readBar() == "123456"

      where: "this code shoud work with bar enabled or disabled"
      barIsEnabled  | ignored
      true          | _
      false         | _
  }
```

Ref: http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

If you just want to reuse the `then` logic, create a private method and add many `assert` inside it:

```
def "foo"() {
  when:
  def pc = shop.buyPc()

  then:
  matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc)
}
void matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc) {
  assert pc.vendor == "Sunny"
  assert pc.clockRate >= 2333
  assert pc.ram >= 4096
  assert pc.os == "Linux"
}
```

Ref: http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html#_helper_methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use `interaction { doStuff() }` too.

However, if you find that your doStuff() is large and that many of your tests are using the same interaction method then it might be time to think about moving some code in your production class into a separate class and then having one expectation that your class under test calls your new class.

Answer (score 0):

The examples from the Spock doc are pretty good but oddly didn't quite work for me
Ref: https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html#_helper_methods

I needed to add `\` to their example

```
def matchesPreferredConfiguration(pc) {
  pc.vendor == "Sunny" \
  && pc.clockRate >= 2333 \
  && pc.ram >= 4096 \
  && pc.os == "Linux"
}
```